# How not to override some member variables if some condition is set on Parent class?

Tags: c++

I have class C which has some variables which is present on Parent class B.

In the normal scenario I have to override some of variables in the child class C.

Now my question is how I can force the child class not to override the variables in a Parent class?

```
class B
{
  protected:

   int a;
   int b;
 };

class C: B
{
   void somefunc()  
   {
      //I have to prevent this overriding if some condition is set on class B
      a = 10;
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

inIf you want to prevent those variables being overwritten in derived classes make them `private` and provide `protected` getter/setter functions:

```
class B {
protected:

   int getA() const { return a; }
   void seta(int x) {
       if(condition) {
           throw std::runtime_error("Cannot set a");
       }
       a = x;
   }

private:
   int a;
   int b;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you find that you have to conditionally inherit some data members and not others, then you probably need to rethink your design.  In general, data members should be private...even data members of base classes.

I know of no way to conditionally inherit data members.  Your best option would be to do something like:

```
class B {...};
class D1 : public B { int a; ... };
class D2 : public B { int a; int b; ... };    

enum class Option { OneArg, TwoArgs };

std::unique_ptr<B> make_b(Option const opt)
{
   std::unique_ptr<B> b;
   switch(opt) {
   case(Option::OneArg):  b = std::make_unique<D1>(...some args...); break;
   case(Option::TwoArgs): b = std::make_unique<D2>(...some args...); break;
   }
   return std::move(b);
}
```

This way, the derived classes have the private data members they need, and you conditionally construct the *derived* type, NOT the base type.

Not sure if this meets your need, but the bottomline is this: data members should be reserved for derived types; and those data members should be private, at that.  Base classes should serve as interfaces--you should run the other way if you feel the need to start putting function implementation inside of them.